# How to join base path with path starting from current directory

Tags: python, subdirectory, pathlib

In the following code, `dirpath` starts from current directory something like `./x/y`. Then I want to add fullname of current directory to it, but it results `/root/./x/y/file.txt`, but I want `/root/x/y/file.txt`

```
def get_files(self):
        cur_path = Path().resolve()
        print("cur_path:", cur_path)
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
            for filename in [f for f in filenames if "scored_" in f]:
                dfname = os.path.join(cur_path, dirpath, filename)
                tag = dfname.replace("/","_")
                print("dfname:", dfname)
                self.dflist[tag.strip()] = dfname.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths)

```
from pathlib import PurePath

PurePath('/root','./x/y','filename')
```

returns:

```
PurePosixPath('/root/x/y/filename')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
import os
def get_files(self):
        cur_path = Path().resolve()
        print("cur_path:", cur_path)
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
            for filename in [f for f in filenames if "scored_" in f]:
                #dfname = os.path.join(cur_path, dirpath, filename)
                #Used normpath to remove dot while joining current directory & directory path
                dfname=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(cur_path, dirpath, filename))
                tag = dfname.replace("/","_")
                print("dfname:", dfname)
                self.dflist[tag.strip()] = dfname.strip()
```